# Simple C substring implementation

Tags: c, string, pointers, substring

I'm trying to implement a substring function in C. Here's what I have so far:

```
char *substring(const char* str, int beg, int n)
{
   char *ret = malloc(n+1); 
   strncpy(ret, (str + beg), n);
   *(ret+n) = '\n';

   return ret;    
}
```

However, when I have this main function:

```
int main()
{
   char *a = "thisisalongstring";
   char *c;

   c = substring(a, 2, 5);
   printf("%s", c);

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
isisa
<random characters>
```

Any help debugging the code?

Comment: `<random characters> ` It's because you are accesing random-memory. `printf()` requires a `\0` to know where your region memory ends.

Comment: More readable if you declare char * as s instead of c

Answer (score 7):

you should null terminate the string.

```
*(ret+n) = '\n';
```

Should be

```
*(ret+n) = 0;
```

**Note:**

You should also make sure the substring doesn't exceed the string size:

```
beg+n < strlen(str)
```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to make sure that `beg` is actually _inside_ the string, or you could do something like `substring("foo", 10, 10)` which would lead to undefined behaviour. `strncpy` is able to cope with to long lengths though, so no check for that should be needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mistake, it should have been '\0' in the first place not '\n'. But 0 works perfectly fine as well. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `<=` for these checks like `if(beg+n <= strlen(str) && beg <= strlen(str)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also check this

```
str != NULL
```

and

```
n > 0
```

may be the `beg` should be checked, too. Also you can count from the end when `beg` is a negative number.

for example, for `char *a = "thisisalongstring";`, `substring( a, -1, 1 )` means the last char in the string, which is `g`.